How do I add up the value of two cells
I'm not a programmer. I need to add the Litr value to the Total value (the sum of the DataGrid rows).
public int Litr { get; set; }
public int? Total => DataEnters.Where(x => x.Litrs.HasValue).Sum(x => x.Litrs.Value);
How to write an expression correctly
Summa= Total + Litr ???

"does not work" and "returns an error" are both very vague descriptions. Please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints and edit your question to be much clearer.

‘var summa = (Total ?? 0) + Litr;‘
Total is nullable. To avoid issues  when Total is null, we use the null-coalescing operator (??). This operator will return 0 if Total is null.
